# Failing to install Ubuntu creates new UEFI OS entries in my BIOS boot list

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I really can't come up with a good enough title to describe the problem I'm running into.  It's a bunch of things.  I think I'm missing some important knowledge in a few areas, and it might even be a "tales from tech support" kind of situation.

I have a system with these specs:

- ASUS m5a97 R2.0 motherboard
- 256GB Crucial MX100 SSD
- 1TB HD pulled from an old HP pre-built
- 500GB Samsung EVO 850

Among other parts, but they're probably not important here.  On the 256GB Crucial I have installed Windows 10.  I am using the 500GB drive as general storage space, sort of how you would use an external hard drive.

On the 1TB HD I had installed Ubuntu 15.04.  After some short stint with it back when I was using an AMD GPU, it began refusing to boot properly and so I hadn't touched it in a while.  I recently bought an Nvidia card and wanted to try my luck again.  I was able to boot into Ubuntu without problems, unlike before, however the version of the OS is out of date and I would like to replace it with 18.04.

My memory is a little fuzzy, but I was somehow able to get this 15.04 version installed without the use of a USB.  I think this is how I did it:

1. Entirely erase the contents of the 500GB drive
2. Reformat the drive as NTFS and extract the Ubuntu 15.04 ISO into the root folder
3. Boot the machine, automatically running the installer
4. Install Ubuntu onto the 1TB drive
5. Begin using the 500GB drive as general storage for both OS's

The installation was less painful than I was expecting at the time, however it was that I got it done.

Using that memory, I decided to try installing 18.04 in some similar way.  However, this time the 500GB drive is being used, and I can't just wipe the whole thing.  So I erased the 1TB drive, reformatted it as NTFS, and extracted the ISO contents there.  I boot up, and see that the grub bootloader doesn't recognize the filesystem.  Hmm.  This is where my memory must be wrong.

So instead, I try again by partitioning the 1TB drive with a small FAT32 region at the beginning of the drive and leave the rest free.  And hooray!  The Ubuntu installer appears.  Great.  I go through the prompts and manually select my drive and partitioning, opting to use the entire 1TB drive and coalesce the FAT32 region.  I get past this step, and run into:

`The installer needs to commit changes to partition tables, but cannot do so because partitions on the following could not be unmounted: /cdrom`

I don't know what this means at first.  I have a misbehaving CD drive pulled from that same HP computer from 2007.  I turn off the machine, take out the CD drive, and try again.  Except this time... where is the Ubuntu installer?  My BIOS tells me the 1TB drive is not bootable when I try.

I boot back into Windows where I'm doing all this drive management and see that the partitions have been unaltered and the extracted ISO files are still where I left them.  Okay... how about erasing the drive and repeating what I did before?  I restart the computer and... nothing.

At this point I'm just seeing what sticks.  I erase the drive and put the FAT32 portion at the *end*.  I restart, and wow - it worked!  But I run into the same error during installation.  I look up what this means - it's basically telling me that I can't install Ubuntu on the installation media.

So I shrink the 500GB enough for a 2GB FAT32 portion because I'm not using all of it and stick the iso contents there.  Reboot, and the installer comes up again.  Except I left it unattended for more than three seconds and the grub menu disappears.  I reflexively restart the machine so that I can just choose to jump straight into the installer.  But the installer is gone, again.  Wat.

It's at this point I'm noticing some strange things happening in the BIOS.  The boot list is filling with multiple copies of "UEFI OS," which basically just leads to the BIOS's advanced settings.  I don't know how to remove these.

I try this one more time.  I extend the old 500GB volume, then shrink it again and make the end FAT32.  Blah blah blah, the installer still doesn't show up.  Running yet another experiment, I try doing the same thing but making the FAT32 just a little bit smaller so that it begins slightly offset from where it was before.

This is a success for some reason and I get into the installer.  I get past partitioning.  Everything seems like it's going swimmingly... but halfway through I'm told it's impossible to install the bootloader on this drive?  Well I can't really put it anywhere else, so I guess that's it then.

Whether or not I plan on continuing this charade, my boot list now looks like this and I don't see any options to fix it:

[image]

TL;DR... help?

Answer (score 0):

There are all sort of possibilities here, but here's a short version of 
my recommendation:

- Delete all the FAT32 partitions that you don't really need.
- Get the install ISO onto a USB drive
  (On linux: dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=16M; replace 
   sdc with the correct device name for the USB drive)
- Boot from the USB drive and install onto the 1TB drive, after wiping
  all partitions from it, and make sure the partition table is GPT.
- Don't let it write to the MBR on any of your window's disks. Notice if the grub detects the windows installation at the end. If it does, you can set this disk to be default boot disk in BIOS and use the grub menu to choose between 18.04/Windows boot.
- Hopefully BIOS won't show you all the UEFI entries from the partitions you deleted. Otherwise, you'll have to search up on how to remove them from BIOS. This maybe helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/930725/how-to-delete-os-from-boot-menu

I recently installed 18.04 LTS in a similar process on a Dell.

Comment: I should note my disks are now partitioned the way they were before, at least according to Windows.  So these UEFI OS entries don't correspond with actual partitions anymore, they're just there.